Minecraft: mineflayer bot is just leaving the lan world while whisper method is executed. Version 1.20.1
If a player whispers to the bot it crashes when it comes to the bot.whisper method. The bot just goes offline and quit running. No error messages, just quitting.
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')

const options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 25566,
    auth: 'microsoft',
};

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Server Port: ", async ans => {
    if(ans) {
        options.port = ans
    }
    await rl.close();
    bot = mineflayer.createBot(options)

    bot.on('whisper', (username, message) => {
        if (username === bot.username) return
        //bot.chat('Check')
        console.log(username)
        console.log(message)
        bot.whisper(username, (message))
    })

    bot.on('error', err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
});

But with the bot.chat method would it work perfectly.
